# Sumar textFields incluyendo vacíos

Tags: java

Quisiera saber qué sentencia se puede hacer para que no me bote error si dejo espacios en blanco.

Por ejemplo tengo 11 `textField` en un `JFrame` en netbeans. Si yo lleno esos 11, me hace la suma así normal, pero si por ejemplo de esos 11 sólo quiero llenar 5 o 2 o 3 o 7 o 4 o 1, etc; me bota error si dejo esos en blanco, y ya no me hace la suma.

¿Cómo puedo solucionar el problema? Yo sé que con un `IgnoreCase` puedo hacer que no me deje los espacios en blanco cuando lleno un formulario, pero no sé cómo hacer para que deje que los espacios estén en blanco y siga ejecutando la suma común y corriente.

O sea, que lo cuente como si fuera un 0 pero sin que se ponga cero en la suma.

```
    double pro1; double pro2; double pro3; double pro4; double pro5; double pro6; double pro7; double pro8; double pro9; double pro10; double pro11;
    double vtnum1; double vtnum2; double vtnum3; double vtnum4; double vtnum5; double vtnum6; double vtnum7; double vtnum8; double vtnum9; double vtnum10; double vtnum11;
    double pnum1; double pnum2; double pnum3; double pnum4; double pnum5; double pnum6; double pnum7; double pnum8; double pnum9; double pnum10; double pnum11;
    double ivita; double totalito; double subtotalito;

    pro1=Double.parseDouble(num1.getText());
    pro2=Double.parseDouble(num2.getText());
    pro3=Double.parseDouble(num3.getText());
    pro4=Double.parseDouble(num4.getText());
    pro5=Double.parseDouble(num5.getText());
    pro6=Double.parseDouble(num6.getText());
    pro7=Double.parseDouble(num7.getText());
    pro8=Double.parseDouble(num8.getText());
    pro9=Double.parseDouble(num9.getText());
    pro10=Double.parseDouble(num10.getText());
    pro11=Double.parseDouble(num11.getText());

    pnum1=Double.parseDouble(precio1.getText());
    pnum2=Double.parseDouble(precio2.getText());
    pnum3=Double.parseDouble(precio3.getText());
    pnum4=Double.parseDouble(precio4.getText());
    pnum5=Double.parseDouble(precio5.getText());
    pnum6=Double.parseDouble(precio6.getText());
    pnum7=Double.parseDouble(precio7.getText());
    pnum8=Double.parseDouble(precio8.getText());
    pnum9=Double.parseDouble(precio9.getText());
    pnum10=Double.parseDouble(precio10.getText());
    pnum11=Double.parseDouble(precio11.getText());

    vtnum1=pro1*pnum1;
    vtnum2=pro2*pnum2;
    vtnum3=pro3*pnum3;
    vtnum4=pro4*pnum4;
    vtnum5=pro5*pnum5;
    vtnum6=pro6*pnum6;
    vtnum7=pro7*pnum7;
    vtnum8=pro8*pnum8;
    vtnum9=pro9*pnum9;
    vtnum10=pro10*pnum10;
    vtnum11=pro11*pnum11;

    String valtota1=vtnum1 + "";
    String valtota2=vtnum2 + "";
    String valtota3=vtnum3 + "";
    String valtota4=vtnum4 + "";
    String valtota5=vtnum5 + "";
    String valtota6=vtnum6 + "";
    String valtota7=vtnum7 + "";
    String valtota8=vtnum8 + "";
    String valtota9=vtnum9 + "";
    String valtota10=vtnum10 + "";
    String valtota11=vtnum11 + "";

    num12.setText(valtota1);
    num13.setText(valtota2);
    num14.setText(valtota3);
    num15.setText(valtota4);
    num16.setText(valtota5);
    num17.setText(valtota6);
    num18.setText(valtota7);
    num19.setText(valtota8);
    num20.setText(valtota9);
    num21.setText(valtota10);
    num22.setText(valtota11);

    subtotalito=vtnum1+vtnum2+vtnum3+vtnum4+vtnum5+vtnum6+vtnum7+vtnum8+vtnum9+vtnum10+vtnum11;
    String st= subtotalito+"";
    subtotal.setText(st);

    ivita=subtotalito*0.12;
    String i= ivita+"";
    iva.setText(i);

    totalito=subtotalito+ivita;
    String t= totalito+"";
    total.setText(t);

}
```

Comment: Agrega tu código además de la explicación .

Comment: Agrega tu código, lo más conveniente es que al momento de que tomes el valor lo evalues, y si es 'vacio' o nulo lo iguales a 0 para que se ejecute sin problemas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tendrias que agregar algo como esto para cada uno de tus entradas:

```
if(pnum1=='' || pnum1==null){
 pnum1=0.00;
}
```

Comment: @ M. Gress .. LO que hago es colocar ese código en el mio pero me sale error me podrías dar el ejemplo con base a el código en que parte debería ir  .. estoy trabajando en un Jbutton de un Jframe.. Gracias

Answer (score 2):

Complementando la respueta de [M. Gress](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/30839/m-gress) (lo siento, el sistema aún no me permite añadir comentarios)

Lo más ideal sería que hicieras una función para reducir el tamaño del código y también facilitar su mantenimiento y reutilización.

En concreto, una función similar a esta

```
private double StringToDouble (String valor) {
 // Control de null, espacios en blanco y campos vacios.
 if(valor==null || valor.replace(" ","").equals(""))
  {
   return 0;
  }
 /*OJO: Con el trim eliminamos los espacios de los extremos, 
entiendo que si tiene espacios entre caracteres (ejemplo, "33 4" )
es un error del usuario y de ti depende si quieres o no tratarlo. 
Con un   valor.replace(" ","") trataría ese caso como un 334 */

 return Double.parseDouble(valor.trim());  

}
```

Así pues, la modificación quedaría más limpia de leer

```
pro1=StringToDouble(num1.getText());
```

Editado añadiendo cambios sugeridos por [Luiggi Mendoza](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/227/luiggi-mendoza)

Comment: @ Macupo.. Lo que hago es colocar ese código en el mio pero me sale error me podrías dar el ejemplo con base a el código en que parte debería ir .. estoy trabajando en un JButton de un JFrame.. Gracias

Comment: Lo que hago con el pro1 deberás hacerlo con todos los pro1...pro11 y con todos los pnum. Al fina lo unico que haces es decirle que si el texto que te pasan es vacio, te devuelva 0, en caso contrario, te lo convierte a valor númerico (Double.parseDouble). He añadido una pequeña corrección, ahora debería compilarte bien.

Comment: Te funcionó @paola ?

Comment: No he leido todo el problema, pero en Java las cadenas se comparan con `equals` no con `==`. La validación debería ser `if (valor == null || "".equals(valor)) { return 0; } ...`

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza gracias por el aporte, corregido.

Comment: Adicional, creo que debería ser `return Double.parseDouble(valor.trim())` en caso que el texto ingresado tenga espacios en blanco adicionales, ya sea antes o después del número.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza gracias por el aporte, añadido el trim.

Answer (score 1):

Una opción es usar la librería commons lang, agrega el archivo jar a tu proyecto desde tu IDE. Si usas maven o gradle lo agregas fácil como dependencia.

La librería la descargas de [aqui](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.5/commons-lang3-3.5.jar)

A tu código le deberías agregar esto (una vez teniendo la libreria cargada a tu proyecto)

```
pro1=Double.parseDouble(StringUtils.defaultIfBlank(num1.getText(), "0" ) );
```

Lo que hace el código anterior es devolverte un "0" si num.getText() es null, cadena vacia o una cadena con espacios.